# Spring Bean Init Order

Tags: java, spring

I have two Spring Beans as follows:

```
@Service
public class A{
}

@Service
public class B{
   @Autowired A a;

   public B(){
      a.doSomething();
   }
```

The problem is that it is not guareenteed that A will be init earlier than B. So I will get a NullPointerException in B().

Is there anyway that I can specify this dependency in Spring?

Comment: How are you retrieving your instance of B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any autowiring in Spring framework will happen *after* the bean has been constructed. Therefore, it is not possible to use autowired members from the constructor itself (as seen in [Autowired javadoc page](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html)). Your options are to either put the annotation on the constructor itself and make it accept the other bean as parameter which wil then work:

```
@Service
public class B {

  @Autowired
  public B(A a) {
     a.doSomething();
  }
}
```

or to use the `@PostConstruct` annotation on a separate method which will be guaranteed to execute after the bean is constructed and will have all references wired correctly:

```
@Service
public class B{

  @Autowired
  A a;

  @PostConstruct
  public moreSetup() {
     a.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring is capable of detecting these dependencies automatically. It knows to create A before B based on the `@Autowired` annotation (or more formally - when creating the instance of B, Spring detects that it needs an A, and will instantiate the A if it has not done so already).

Comment: unfortunately it seems Spring is not smart enough in my case. I got an NPE when using a in b. I am using 3.0.2.

Comment: @nababa I don't see how that's possible; Spring handles dependency management like this just fine. It's likely something else is wrong.

Comment: how is your context started? are you using `<context:component-scan>`?